# iOS UIScrollView - detect paging swipe - Middle icon big other icons smaller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a scrollview that always shows three items. I need the middle item to be big, and the items on the left and the right to be small.

My question is, how can I detect a paging swipe? What I was planning on doing is everytime the scrollview has been "paged", we detect it then check all the items in the scrollview - if the item is in the middle "frame" we make it bigger, otherwise it is smaller.

Am I going about this the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a delegate on your `UITableView` that accepts the `scrollViewDidScroll:` message (or perhaps `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`, depending on your needs). See [the UITableViewDelegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html).

I do this kind of check inside `scrollViewDidScroll`. I check the current content offset, and if the rectangle formed by the current offset and the size of the scroll view frame are suitably intersecting with one of my scroll view pages, then I have that `page` update. Here, you might want to scale each item proportionally to how close it is to the center of the current content offset (which would create a nice dock style magnification effect for your scroller).

Edit: So, hypothetical untested pseudocode for an array of "items" in a scroller that pages horizontally.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  CGPoint *currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;

  for (UIView *item in itemsToDisplay)
  {
    // The location in the entire scroll view canvas at which
    // we consider this item to "live"
    CGPoint *naturalCentre = item.naturalCentre;

    // How far from our desired point are we?
    CGFloat scale = 100 - fabs(naturalCentre.x - contentOffset.x);
    // Clamp this to positive values only, and normalize from 0.5 to 1
    scale = 0.5 + (scale < 0 : 0 ? (scale / 200));

    // Scale this view accordingly
    item.layer.contentsScale = scale;
  }
}
```

That's written off the cuff, and will need rather a lot of debugging.

Comment: That is a great solution! Could you give me a short code example on how to scale the items porportionally to how close they are to the center of the content offset? That sounds ultra smooth!

Comment: This actually all works great, but the problem is all the items scale up or down. How do we detect which item in the scrollview is within the "naturalCentre"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here - everything should scale, proportionaly to how far the `contentOffset` is from the natural centre of the item. If the `contentOffset` is exactly at the natural centre, the scale is 1. The further it is from the the natural centre, the closer the scale gets to 0.5. To "detect" which item is in the centre, you just look at the offset and compare to the centre of each item?

Comment: What attribute on a UIView are we comparing the offset against? The View's center/origin? Frame? You have "item.naturalCentre". Where is that value coming from?